# JWT token signing works in jwt.io but not in my code

Tags: .net, security, jwt, public-key-encryption, open-banking

Trying to sign a JWT token using jose-jwt but for some reason I'm failing miserably to understand why it's not working as expected.

The signing part is working in my test but if I use this to request the server resource it fails. But if I paste this to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and paste my private key it works perfectly when I try to request server resources with this new token

So it looks like even though it seems to be working in my .net code base, it's not actually signing the token.

I've wrote few tests and it does works in terms of signing and verifying without any issues. [gist](https://gist.github.com/damithg/1c781d100f1981073e3923722e5a4ade)

```
public class TestUsingJoseJwt
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Nonce { get; set; }
    public JsonNetSerializer JsonNetSerializer { get; set; }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        Identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        JsonNetSerializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanGenerateSignedJwtUsingJose()
    {
        // Get the private/ public keys
        var privateKeyTexts = File.ReadAllText("FULL PATH TO MY PRIVATE KEY");
        var publicKeyTexts = File.ReadAllText("FULL PATH TO MY PUBLIC KEY");

        var signedClaim = CreateJwtToken("AAC_1c0b51b0-d673-4872-898e-ce9d6d3f0482", Identifier, Nonce);

        var token = CreateToken(signedClaim, privateKeyTexts);
        var payload = DecodeToken(token, publicKeyTexts);

        var expected = JsonNetSerializer.Serialize(signedClaim);

        payload.Should()
            .Be(expected, "provided object should be correctly serialized in the token");
    }

    public static string CreateToken(SignedClaim signedClaim, string privateRsaKey)
    {
        RSAParameters rsaParams;
        using (var tr = new StringReader(privateRsaKey))
        {
            var pemReader = new PemReader(tr);
            var keyPair = pemReader.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
            if (keyPair == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not read RSA private key");
            }
            var privateRsaParams = keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
            rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateRsaParams);
        }
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            //Dictionary<string, object> payload = claims.ToDictionary(k => k.Type, v => (object)v.Value);
            var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(signedClaim);
            return Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
        }
    }

    public string DecodeToken(string token, string publicRsaKey)
    {
        RSAParameters rsaParams;

        using (var tr = new StringReader(publicRsaKey))
        {
            var pemReader = new PemReader(tr);
            var publicKeyParams = pemReader.ReadObject() as RsaKeyParameters;
            if (publicKeyParams == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not read RSA public key");
            }
            rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(publicKeyParams);
        }
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            // This will throw if the signature is invalid
            return Jose.JWT.Decode(token, rsa, JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
        }
    }

    public SignedClaim CreateJwtToken(string consentId, string identifier, string nonce)
    {
        return new SignedClaim
        {
            Aud = "https://sandbox.api.endpoint",
            Scope = "openid accounts",
            Iss = "bdn-8Zpkl9dCbN2tArm2TrgretrtKSexT2XxQ26uL8B",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            RedirectUri = "TEST_REDIRECT_URL",
            State = identifier,
            Exp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
            Nonce = nonce,
            ClientId = "bdn-8Zpkl9dCbN2tAeerertreterexT2XxQ26uL8B",
            Claims = new Claims
            {
                IdToken = new IdToken
                {
                    Acr = new Acr
                    {
                        Essential = true,
                        Value = "urn:openbanking:psd2:sca",
                    },
                    OpenbankingIntentId = new Acr
                    {
                        Essential = true,
                        Value = consentId,
                    },
                },
                Userinfo = new Userinfo
                {
                    OpenbankingIntentId = new Acr
                    {
                        Value = consentId,
                        Essential = true,
                    },
                },
            },
        };
    }
}
```

I'm pretty much in the end of the tunnel with confused than ever before :( Can anyone shed any lights as to why it works when I manually copy/paste the private key in jwt.io but the code is failing to sign the token please?

Here's a sample token request

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.Uce2-ZcqQk3JAABltywib79UADhh7HoFv2e6pa0q1b_JuZUeaHk0L_7iC__hVY-TCfG5dmjIFWi80ioQ9hM5WeIX2RLRhhjk8s8pjrOmY243gg2_YJNKK9qwVZtHbieY8OI46ZH8CnQhSILAtVVgqXZeXtFPfk4VvW_yJf4DELSoDtB3hSxoMZtjGbnF5JBzNB0fFBpnTzKQ7a3RPsL_rJUc9IbXOgXBoF-OmlAFNu8F4l5gMmrL146WSSytkUBVQQhDxxc0JQHcz3TqbapxcWSuchu0-nGR8cIXimvQKyaWpG0OISUA-4H5dH3GHNbxOBDT7wTKYLzdG5tj_d9beQ
```

Comment: **it's not actually signing the token** So, how does your token look like? Would be helpful if you could edit your question and add the token.

Comment: CreateJwtToken actually creates the object and as part of CreateToken I pass the Json object to Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, JwsAlgorithm.RS256). What's coming out of this is I believe the signed representation of my token

Comment: What exception you get on the server resource , did you try to see in the logs..And what is the token lifetime.... value of exp attribute...

Comment: exp is valid for 10 minutes. The token works just fine if I go to jwt.io and validate with my private key and then use it in the request. So that proves the token is correct but when I sign it in my .net code it doesn't seems to have signed. unfortunately I have no way of checking the logs in the other end of the wire.

Comment: Anyone able to shed some lights on this guys? Pretty desperate to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's the Json Serialization that messes things up.

```
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(signedClaim);
```

I've just removed this and pass the object directly to Encode and that seems to have fixed it. Bit annoyed as I didn't spot that earlier. But at least it works now.